# Hide menu bar only for full-screen videos

Tags: applescript, menu-bar, keybindings, shortcuts-app, monterey

I like to have the menu bar present when using apps in full screen. So, I have the auto-hide option unchecked. However, when I want to view a netflix or youtube video in full screen, the menu bar is still there. I would like for the menu bar to hide only in these specific occasions. I tried looking for a keyboard shortcut to hide the menu bar but none exists. I tried to make a shortcut using the Shortcut app and apple script. I am using Monterey.

[image]

Comment: The **AppleScript** _code_ you are trying to use is not applicable to **macOS Monterey**, (it's actual not applicable to any version of **macOS** since **macOS Mojave** ). In **macOS Mojave** it was moved to the **Dock** _preference pane_ and to the **Dock & Menu Bar** _preference pane_ in **macOS Big Sur**.

Comment: What is the correct script for Monterey?

Comment: The same that is is for **macOS Big Sur** as I've already mentioned it was moved to **Dock & Menu Bar** _preference pane_ and is also applicable to **macOS Monterey**, otherwise I would have stated an explicit change for **macOS Monterey** too.

Comment: So change "System Preferences" to "Dock & Menu Bar"?

Comment: @user3439894 ??

Comment: RE: "So change "System Preferences" to "Dock & Menu Bar"?" No you do not 'change "System Preferences" to "Dock & Menu Bar"' you `reveal` the `pane id` for **Dock & Menu Bar** instead of **General** and you change **General** to "Dock & Menu Bar" for the _window_ being targeted. That said though, scripting the **UI** with such minimal _code_ can be problematic as you've not included any appropriate _error handling_ or accounting for timing requirements/issues between events.

Comment: Is there an answer to this?

Comment: @bilogic I haven't figured it out yet

Answer (score 1):

I had the opposite requirement. I wanted the bar hidden most of the time, but show only in 1 or 2 apps. I suppose you could do the reverse, but I'm not sure how to isolate only YouTube if you are using Chrome.

```bash
# override the menu bar to show/hide
## 1. get app's ID from its name
osascript -e 'id of app "NAME"'

## 2. override the menu bar show/hide: true/false
defaults write apps.id.from.step-1 AppleMenuBarVisibleInFullscreen -bool false

## 3. to undo this setting
defaults delete apps.id.from.step-1 AppleMenuBarVisibleInFullscreen
```

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't seem to work though. I restarted chrome and wnet into full window but it's still there